# Getting started with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, server-side

I know C# and I want to start with ASP.NET (I already know how to build websites, using PHP).
I need good resource for ASP.NET (MVC, the latest version).

I have found other qustions, seemiler to mine, but what I want is your recommendations.

Comment: I have heard the developing proccess is faster.
Plus I can use C#, which is much more powerfull than PHP.

In addition, it is good to be farmilliar with different technologist, even only superficial

Comment: If you're going to be doing any kind of web development and aren't already familiar with the concept of layers, you absolutely must read http://imar.spaanjaars.com/416/building-layered-web-applications-with-microsoft-aspnet-20-part-1

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET website is a good place to start:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

I would recommend [reading some documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview), [follow some tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4), and give it a shot.

If you run into any problems, you can always find answers / ask questions on here.

Comment: There are also several books recently released for MVC4, in particular Professional ASP.NET MVC 4, Programming ASP.NET MVC 4, ASP.NET MVC 4 In Action, and Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 will be out in December.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing better than looking at working code for a non-trivial project to learn something new. I'd highly recommend going through the [MVC Music Store tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store) and type in every line by hand to help you remember. By the end you'll have a real good idea of what MVC is and why it's so cool.

Comment: Cool, I'm gonna try this later.

Answer (score 0):

[Wrox's Beginning ASP.NET 4: in C# and VB](https://www.google.com/search?q=Wrox%27s%20Beginning%20ASP.NET%204%3a%20in%20C#%20and%20VB&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) is a great book to start with.